# Clean way to write this query

Tags: linq

I'm looking for a clean way to write this Linq query.

Basically I have a collection of objects with id's, then using nhibernate and Linq, I need to check if the nhibernate entity has a subclass collection where all id's in object collection exist in the nhibernate subclass collection.

If there was just one item this would work:

```
var objectImCheckingAgainst = ... //irrelevant 
where Obj.SubObj.Any(a => a.id == objectImCheckingAgainst.Id)
```

Now I want to instead somehow pass a list of objectImCheckingAgainst and return true only if the Obj.SubObj collection contains all items in list of objectImCheckingAgainst based on Id.

Comment: To be clear, you need `Obj.SubObj` to have matching ids for every item in `objectImCheckingAgainst`, but you don't care about the other way around?

Comment: @Matthew, exactly. Obj.SubObj might have more items. I want to check the subset in objectImCheckingAgainst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534297(v=vs.100).aspx) for this.

```
return objectImCheckingAgainst.GroupJoin(Obj.SubObj,
                                         a => a.Id,
                                         b => b.id,
                                         (a, b) => b.Any())
                              .All(c => c);
```

I believe this query *should* be more or less self-explanatory, but essentially, this joins the two collections using their respective ids as keys, then groups those results. Then for each of those groupings, it determines whether any matches exist. Finally, it ensures that all groupings had matches.

A useful alternative that I sometimes use is `.Count() == 1` instead of the `.Any()`. Obviously, the difference there is whether you want to support multiple elements with the same id matching. From your description, it sounded like that either doesn't matter or is enforced by another means. But that's an easy swap, either way.

An important concept in `GroupJoin` that I know is relevant, but may or may not be obvious, is that the first enumerable (which is to say, the first argument to the extension method, or `objectImCheckingAgainst` in this example) will have all its elements included in the result, but the second one may or may not. It's not like `Join`, where the ordering is irrelevant. If you're used to SQL, these are the elementary beginnings of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

---

Another way you could accomplish this, somewhat more simply but not as efficiently, would be to simply nest the queries:

```
return objectImCheckingAgainst.All(c => Obj.SubObj.Any(x => x.id == c.Id));
```

I say this because it's pretty similar to the example you provided.

I don't have any experience with NHibernate, but I know many ORMs (I believe EF included) will map this to SQL, so efficiency may or may not be a concern. But in general, I like to write LINQ as close to par as I can so it works as well in memory as against a database, so I'd go with the first one I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, really interesting addition to my Linq toolbox.

Comment: I'll keep your answer as accepted, however worth a note, GroupJoin at time of writing is not implemented in nhibernate (yet). So I'm using the workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not well versed in LINQ-to-NHibernate but when using LINQ against any SQL backen it's always important to keep an eye on the generated SQL. I think this where clause...

```
where Obj.SubObj.All(a => idList.Contains(a.id))
```

...will produce the best SQL (having an `IN` statement).

`idList` is a list of `Id`s extracted from the list of `objectImCheckingAgainst` objects.